# Getters in RoR's model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to learn Ruby and RoR.
I'm confused by Ruby's magic:)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'digest/sha1'
    validates :login, :password, :email, { presence: true }
    validates :login, :email, { uniqueness: true }

    before_save :hash_password

    private def hash_password
        if password_chanched?
            puts @password.class.name
            puts password
            password = 'test_pass'
            puts password

            # @password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)      it works
        end
    end
end
```

console:

```
>> t = User.new login: 'Test', email: 'abc@def.ghi', password: 'trololo'
#<User id: nil, login: "Test", password: "trololo", email: "abc@def.ghi", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> t.save
NilClass
trololo
test_pass
true

>> t.password
"trololo"
```

So my question is:

What does *password* returns? And what have I to modify in callbacks?

Actually, this before_validation callback works just fine:

```
def downcase_login_and_email
    login.downcase!
    email.downcase!
end
```

Comment: not sure I understand the question, are u asking about `password` or callbacks ?

Comment: Both:)
I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when I write

> password = 'test_pass'

I don't use the setter (like *any_instance.password = 'test_pass'*), but I create a local variable *password* which does not make any sense to class instance.

I have to use *self*:

```
    if password_changed?
        puts password # trololo
        self.password = 'test_pass'
        puts password # test_pass
    end
```

So I have to read more about Ruby:)